# Given a list of ranges, find all combination for these ranges that sums upto k

Tags: python, math, dynamic-programming

I have 34 ranges of numbers.
For example :

```
x1 = {25,35}
x2 = {28,36}
x3 = {15,20}
.
.
x34 = {28,37}
```

I have to find all combinations such that i choose a number from every range and all those 34 numbers sums up to k.

For example :

```
let k = 600

so from x1 - we pick 26

from x2 - we pick 29

.

.

and from x34 we pick 16.

Then, x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + … + x34 = 600.
```

I want all such combinations.

Is it feasible with some algorithm?

I want to implement this in python.

Comment: are both ends of the ranges included?

Comment: yes I am including them. @moeassal

Answer (score 1):

`range(a, b)` a included, b excluded.
So here the *real ranges* are:

```
{20, 25}
{30, 36}
{10, 39}
```

```
all_ranges = [range(20, 26), range(30, 37), range(10, 40)]

def get_combinations(ranges, k):
    if ranges.__len__() == 0:
        return int(k == 0)

    combinations = 0
    for i in ranges[0]:
#        if k - i < 0:
#            break
        combinations += get_combinations(ranges[1:], k - i)
    return combinations

print(get_combinations(all_ranges, 70))
```

Instead of adding numbers till they reach `k`, we will subtract from `k` till reaching zero.

```
if ranges.__len__() == 0:
    return int(k == 0)
```

This is the block which terminates the recursive. Basically if we subtract each number picked from the ranges from `k`, then the result must be zero.

```
combinations = 0
for i in ranges[0]:
    combinations += get_combinations(ranges[1:], k - i)
```

Note that the parts commented are for efficiency only.
So we are picking a number here, we choose it initially to be `k`. We then loop over all values of the first range, and get the combinations of the new `k - i` with the new ranges `ranges[1:]`. You can see how those things fit together.

### Edit and correct answer

Pardon me, I didn't notice OP needed the combinations themselves. Nonetheless, I left the above code for future visitors.

Using the same logic as above, we can get all combinations in a 2 dimensional list.

```
from copy import deepcopy
all_ranges = [range(20, 26), range(30, 37), range(10, 40)]

def get_combinations(ranges, k, initial_combination=None):
    if not initial_combination:
        initial_combination = []
    combinations = []
    if ranges.__len__() == 1:
        for i in ranges[0]:
            if k - i < 0:
                return combinations
            elif k - i == 0:
                _ = deepcopy(initial_combination)
                _.append(i)
                combinations.append(_)
        return combinations

    for i in ranges[0]:
        _ = deepcopy(initial_combination)
        _.append(i)
        combinations += get_combinations(ranges[1:], k - i, _)
    return combinations

get_combinations(all_ranges, 70)
```

Note: [deepcopy functionality](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/#:~:text=In%20case%20of%20deep%20copy,using%20%E2%80%9Cdeepcopy()%E2%80%9D%20function.)

### Computational Efficiency HACK

```
from copy import deepcopy
all_ranges = [range(10, 40), range(20, 30), range(40, 50)]


def get_minimums():
    m = []
    for index, r in enumerate(all_ranges):
        m.append(sum([_.start for _ in all_ranges[index + 1:]]))

minimums = get_minimums() #[60, 40, 0]


def get_combinations(ranges, k, initial_combination=None):
    if not initial_combination:
        initial_combination = []
    combinations = []
    if ranges.__len__() == 1:
        for i in ranges[0]:
            if k - i < 0:
                break
            elif k - i == 0:
                _ = deepcopy(initial_combination)
                _.append(i)
                print(_)
                combinations.append(_)

        return combinations

    minimum = minimums[-ranges.__len__()]
    for i in range(ranges[0].start, ranges[0].stop):
        if k - minimum - i < 0:
            break

        _ = deepcopy(initial_combination)
        _.append(i)
        combinations += get_combinations(ranges[1:], k - i, _)
    return combinations

get_combinations(all_ranges, 90)
```

Comment: This is giving us the number of solutions. Can we also find all the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools' product method to check all combinations between n number of arrays.

For example:

```
import itertools
a = [1,2]
b = ['a' , 'b']
c = list(itertools.product(a,b))
>> [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

So if you want to know all the combinations that make a given number, you only have to iterate in the final list and check all the results.

```
import itertools

x1 = range(25,35)
x2 = range(28,36)
x3 = range(15,20)

result = []
for item in list(itertools.product(x1,x2,x3)):
    if sum(item) == 75:
        result.append(item)

print(result)
>> [(25, 31, 19), (25, 32, 18), (25, 33, 17), (25, 34, 16), .....]
```

If you don't know previously know the number of ranges you simply use the * operator in the itertools.product and the code will be the same

```
ranges = [range(1,5), range(5,29), range(3, 400), ...]

#STUFF

itertools.product(*ranges)
```

Comment: I have 34 ranges and it will be a lot of computation just to find out all the products. :(